# Problem converting image array of interleaved data to non-interleaved data using C++/CUDA and CImg

Tags: c++, image, cuda, cimg

I'm trying to convert an array of RGBRGB values into an array of RRGGBB values using CUDA. The code i have now is:

```
__global__ void convertToo(UCHAR *imageData, UCHAR *outData, size_t dataSize)
{
    size_t i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (i >= dataSize) return;
    auto index = ((i % 3) * (dataSize / 3)) + i;
    if (index >= dataSize) return;
    auto iVal = imageData[i];
    outData[index] = iVal;
}
```

(the index and Ival are there for debugging purposes)
The code that calls it is:

```
auto blockSize = size / 1024;
convertToo <<<blockSize, 1024>> > (imageData, outData, size * sizeof(UCHAR));
```

Where imageData is the array containing the RGB values and the outData is where the newly formated data is supposed to go.

```
CImg<unsigned char> image(s.c_str());
CImg<unsigned char> result(s.c_str());

size_t old_sizeX = image.width();
size_t old_sizeY = image.height();
size_t old_spectrum = image.spectrum();
size_t old_depth = image.depth();
size_t size = image.size();
image.permute_axes("cxyz");

UCHAR *imageData, *outData;
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&imageData, sizeof(UCHAR) * size));
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&outData, sizeof(UCHAR) * size));
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());


unsigned char *data = image.data();

gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(imageData, data, sizeof(UCHAR) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

auto blockSize = size / 1024;
convertToo <<<blockSize, 1024>> > (imageData, outData, size * sizeof(UCHAR));
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(result.data(), outData, size * sizeof(UCHAR), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

image.permute_axes("yzcx");

CImgDisplay main_disp(image, "Original image");
CImgDisplay main_disp2(result, "Blurred image");
while (1)
{
    main_disp.wait();
    main_disp2.wait();
}
std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
```

The problem i get is that when I put the image back together, I don't get the same result (Using CImg) which I logically should. I tried looking at each array and see weather they are correct, but I don't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your computation for `index` is wrong.  Let's break it down.

First you figure out which color component you have (`i % 3`), then adjust that for the correct "page" for that color (`* (datasize / 3)`).  Lastly you add in the offset for the pixel (`i`).

This last part is wrong.  Since each pixel is 3 bytes, you need to divide `i` by 3 to get the correct offset:

```
auto index = ((i % 3) * (dataSize / 3)) + i / 3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have realized that; Been staring myself blind over this. Much appreciated.